# How can the Gemara entertain the possibility that mental health takes priority over a potential danger to life?

Tags: choleh-sick, bava-kamma

[Bava Kamma 60b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.60b.2-4) writes that one should remain indoors when a plague rages outside, quoting three pesukim to support this. While the first passuk establishes the base case, the second passuk establishes that this applies to even a daytime plague. What's puzzling to me is the rationale behind the necessity for the third passuk:

> וכי תימא ה"מ [היכא] דליכא אימה מגואי אבל היכא דאיכא אימה מגואי כי נפיק יתיב ביני אינשי בצוותא בעלמא טפי מעלי ת"ש מחוץ תשכל חרב ומחדרים אימה אע"ג דמחדרים אימה מחוץ תשכל חרב
>
> And if you would say that this matter applies only where there is no fear inside, but where there is fear inside, [one might think that] when he goes out and sits among people in general company it is better, come and hear: “Outside the sword will bereave, and in the chambers terror.” Although there is terror in the chambers, outside the sword will bereave, [so it is safer to remain indoors].

I find this hard to understand. The Gemara seems to be entertaining the possibility that it's preferable to go outside, where there is a risk to one's life, because of his mental health? We push practically everything aside for the sake of saving a life; why would we entertain the possibility that mental health takes precedence over one's physical wellbeing, to the extent that we need a passuk to refute the premise?

Comment: Mental dangers are real dangers too

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/110711/13438

Comment: There are people who react to mental health issues even more that physical dangers. The Torah explains that one must react properly to all kinds of danger. If the Torah would not explain this, people could rationalize behaving improperly for the various situations.

Comment: There are problems of claustrophobia. Sometimes you need to compare the danger of e.g. a panic attack and the danger of an epidemic episode. What is the worse, not an answer but a suggestion for thinking

Comment: A severe anxiety can lead to suicide or aggression

Answer (score 3):

In discussing COVID-19, Rabbi Frand [shared](https://baltimorejewishlife.com/news/news-detail.php?SECTION_ID=1&ARTICLE_ID=128789) a Ben Yehoyada (Bava Kamma 60b) with us in Baltimore that fear stirred by an epidemic can be more deadly than the disease itself.

> [Ben Yehoyada (Bava Kamma 60b)](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14475#p=128&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) – הנה מהרש״א ז״ל פירש הכונה אם אין
>   אתה בורח חוץ לעיר למקום אחראז תעשה תקנה זו להיות מוסגר בביתיך ולא תצא
>   מפתח הבית. והרב עיון יעקב ז"ל פירש הכונה דהבריחה מן העיר היא טובה
>   ונכונה קודם שנתחזק הדבר בעיר אבל דבר בעיר שנתחזק הדבר לא תועיל הבריחה
>   שגם הדבר ילך עמהם למקום שהולכין וכמ"ש מהרי"ל ז"ל (נ) ודע כל זה שכתבו
>   המהרש"א ז"ל והרב עיון יעקב ז"ל הוא בדבר אבל בחולי הקוליר"א אפילו אם
>   נתחזק החולי בעיר טוב שיברח וגם בזה לא יועיל ההסגר בביתו שבעיר יען כי
>   זה החולי של הקוליר"א יזיק לאדם הפחד וההבעתה ויתהווה בו החולי מחמת הפחד
>   וההבעתה אשר יפחד ונבעת ואומרים הרופאים מעשה בדרך משל ומליצה פעם אחת
>   היה חולי הקוליר"א בעיר אחת גדולה וקודם שנתחזק החולי מצא אדם אחד את
>   המשחית הממונה על חולי הקוליר"א ואמר לו כמה נפשות אתה רוצה ליקח ואמר
>   חמשה אלפים וסוף דבר מתו באותה העיר ט"ו אלפים באותו החולי וימצא האיש
>   ההוא לאותו המשחית ויאמר לו למה שקרת שאמרת אתה שליח על מספר חמשה אלפים
>   ולקחת ט"ו אלפים והשיב לא שקרתי כי לא לקחתי בחרבי על ידי אלא רק חמשה
>   אלפים ואותם העשרה מתו מחמת רוב הפחד והבעתה שהיה להם בעבור החולי הזה
>   בעיר - When facing a cholera epidemic, someone asked the destructive
>   angel how many he would kill. "5,000 people will be killed by my
>   sword." When the epidemic was over, 15,000 people perished. He
>   returned to the destructive angel and said, 'liar you said you would
>   only kill 5,000 people yet there are 15,000 people dead!' The angel
>   replied, 'I said the truth. 5,000 people died my by sword, but 10,000
>   people died from their fear.'

Comment: +1 According to this understanding it begs the question about what pshat is in the Maskana

Answer (score 1):

Rashi explains that the person is scared about death from a Malach that would be more likely in the privacy of one's home than with people.

Why? I'm not sure but the issue isn't putting oneself in danger for the sake of mental health  or unfounded fear. The issue is weighing the danger of being inside versus being outside.